# Grobid and Biblio-glutton: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File config/glutton.yml not found

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, grobid

I'm trying to play a bit with grobid and biblio-glutton (https://github.com/kermitt2/biblio-glutton), following the steps found in the documentation I'm now blocked when I want to run the docker compose, the command and error are:

```
docker-compose run biblio java -jar lib/lookup-service-0.2-onejar.jar crossref --input ../../data/crossref-works.2018-09-05.json.xz config/glutton.yml
```

```
Creating biblio-glutton_biblio_run ... done
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File config/glutton.yml not found
        at io.dropwizard.configuration.FileConfigurationSourceProvider.open(FileConfigurationSourceProvider.java:18)
        at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:80)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:126)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:74)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
        at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
        at com.scienceminer.lookup.web.LookupServiceApplication.main(LookupServiceApplication.java:185)
ERROR: 1
```

I'm running Windows 10, CMD with administrative rights and in the folder where I run this command there is a folder called "config" and, inside, there is the glutton.yml file.

**UPDATE 06/09/2022**

The right volume was missing inside the docker compose file (see the data volume):

```
services:
  biblio:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .\data:/app/data
      - .\config:/app/config
```

After this change in the docker compose file, it starts to work.

Answer (score 0):

The right volume was missing inside the docker compose file (see the data volume):

services:
biblio:
build: .
restart: always
ports:
- 8080:8080
volumes:
- .\data:/app/data
- .\config:/app/config

After this change in the docker compose file, it starts to work.